# Stop errorbars from overlapping in matlab

Tags: matlab, errorbar

I have multiple sets of data with standard deviations I need to present - and I've been using error bars.  When I plot multiple sets on the same plot, however, some of the error bars overlap.

Is there an easy way to make it such that the error bars for a certain tick value are slightly offset, such that it's clear they belong to that tick marker, but don't overlap so their spreads are clear?  I have seen a similar question answered and performed with bar graphs, but am having a hard time extending it to errorbar.

Thanks!

Example image, with overlapping error bars:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRA5C.png)

Code used to produce image:

```
val1 = [818.23,819.12,820.73,821.93,819.21];
val2 = [840.04,839.77,841.20,842.54,841.50];
val1std = [14.81,5.17,14.08,20.24,11.95];
val2std = [14.81,5.17,14.08,20.24,11.95];

figure
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
hold on
errorbar(val1,val1std,'ok','linewidth',2,'MarkerSize',6','MarkerFaceColor','k')
errorbar(val2,val2std,'xk','linewidth',2,'MarkerSize',6','MarkerFaceColor','k')
xlabel('Some property (unit)','fontsize',18,'interpreter','latex')
ylabel('Another property (unit)','fontsize',18,'interpreter','latex')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'','0.10','0.08','0.06','0.04','0.02',''}) 
set(get(gca, 'yLabel'), 'Rotation',90);
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
xlim([0 6])
ylim([800 900])
set(gca, ...
    'box', 'on',...
    'tickdir', 'in',...
    'ticklength',[.02 .02],...
    'linewidth',1,...
    'ygrid','off')
set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto','Color',[1,1,1])
h=legend({'data1','data2'})
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) Is the data along the x axis pretty quantized? (are there only certain values it can take on, or is there data across the whole range.) 2) How many overlapping bars would you expect at most? 2? 3? 20?

Comment: Hi Ian: 1) There are only certain values. It's a geometric property (xaxis), and tests were conducted at those 5 values of the geometric property for 2 groups, with a large number of specimens per group. 2) As such, at the present time and for this publication, we would only have 2 overlapping bars.  We want to keep it in this style - that is, we don't want transparent color bars to overlap.  If we could have a slight offset, that would be ideal! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the `x` input to [`errorbar`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbar.html) and add a little offset manually. You can do it as follows. Modified lines are indicated with comments.

```
val1 = [818.23,819.12,820.73,821.93,819.21];
val2 = [840.04,839.77,841.20,842.54,841.50];
val1std = [14.81,5.17,14.08,20.24,11.95];
val2std = [14.81,5.17,14.08,20.24,11.95];

figure
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
hold on
delta = .07; % Adjust manually
errorbar((1:numel(val1))-delta, val1,val1std,'ok','linewidth',2,'MarkerSize',6',...
'MarkerFaceColor','k') % Add X input
errorbar((1:numel(val2))+delta,val2,val2std,'xk','linewidth',2,'MarkerSize',6',...
'MarkerFaceColor','k') % Add X input
xlabel('Some property (unit)','fontsize',18,'interpreter','latex')
ylabel('Another property (unit)','fontsize',18,'interpreter','latex')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'','0.10','0.08','0.06','0.04','0.02',''}) 
set(get(gca, 'yLabel'), 'Rotation',90);
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
xlim([0 6])
ylim([800 900])
set(gca, ...
    'box', 'on',...
    'tickdir', 'in',...
    'ticklength',[.02 .02],...
    'linewidth',1,...
    'ygrid','off')
set(gcf,'paperpositionmode','auto','Color',[1,1,1])
h=legend({'data1','data2'})
set(h,'Interpreter','latex')
```

This gives the following figure.

[image]